# Why My Comparison Counter For QuickSort Does NOT Work?

Tags: python, algorithm, counter, quicksort

My QuickSort implementation, choosing always the first element as a pivot point works. However, when I tried to add counter for comparisons it fails to count properly. My question is how to count the comparisons when using first element as a pivot point? And could someone help me to fix my code.

```
counter = 0
def Partition(L):
    global counter
    pivot = L[0]
    i = 0
    swap = 0
    for j in range(1,len(L)):
        if L[j] <= pivot:
            swap = L[i]
            L[i] = L[j]
            L[j] = swap
            i += 1
            counter += 1

    swap = L[0]
    L[0] = L[i-1]
    L[i-1] = swap
    return QuickSort(L[:i]) + QuickSort(L[i:])


def QuickSort(L):
    if len(L) <= 1:
        return L
    return Partition(L)

print QuickSort([3,9,8,4,6,10,2,5,7,1])
print 'Correct ANS: 25'
print 'My ANS:     ',counter
```

The test case I am using at the end is correct one.

Comment: Sorry but is `25` an already-proved correct answer? Since your implement of quicksort looks good.

Comment: Yes 25 is proved answer, however I fail to reach it.

Comment: it might help to include what answer you do get?

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is that you are including the pivot element in the recursive call to quicksort. The algorithm still works, but it requires more comparisons than necessary. Instead, change the recursive call to:

```
QuickSort(L[:i]) + QuickSort(L[i+1:])
```

And you should be set.

Comment: Does not work again, even it fails to sort properly. I have new idea how to count and then it fails to work. Here you can see it:

Comment: Y = [7, 5, 1, 4, 8, 3, 10, 2, 6, 9]

counter = -len(Y)+1 #<-- Dont count first input in recursion
def Partition(L):
    pivot = L[0]
    i = 0
    swap = 0
    for j in range(1,len(L)):
        if L[j] <= pivot:
            swap = L[i]
            L[i] = L[j]
            L[j] = swap
            i += 1

    swap = L[0]
    L[0] = L[i-1]
    L[i-1] = swap
    print L[:i],L[i:]
    return QuickSort(L[:i]) + QuickSort(L[i:])


def QuickSort(L):
    global counter
    if len(L) >= 1  :
        counter = counter + len(L) - 1
    if len(L) <= 1:
        return L
    return Partition(L)

Comment: Basically, it count the length - 1 on every sub list which is created in the recursion. So as we subtract 1 we do not count pivot element as comparison. As you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it right! The code needs some improvements, but it works!

```
counter = 0
def Partition(L):
    global counter
    pivot = L[0]
    i = 1
    swap = 0
    bigger = []
    pivotList = []
    less = []
    for j in range(1,len(L)):
        if L[j] < pivot:
            swap = L[i]
            L[i] = L[j]
            L[j] = swap
            i += 1

    swap = L[0]
    L[0] = L[i-1]
    L[i-1] = swap

    less = L[:i-1]
    bigger = L[i:]
    pivotList = [L[i-1]] 
    counter += len(less) + len(bigger) # Do NOT COUNT PIVOT AS COMPARISON
    return QuickSort(less)+ pivotList + QuickSort(bigger)


def QuickSort(L):
    if len(L) <= 1:
        return L
    return Partition(L)
#Test case:
QuickSort(7, 5, 1, 4, 8, 3, 10, 2, 6, 9) # correct ANS =  21
print counter
```